# strategy of a maths/science chalk talk interview

Tags: teaching, faculty-application

1.Candidate is to teach 1 out of several topics given. Should there not be any preferrential topic to be taught in the eye of the interviewers? Is there any disadvantage not to choose the hardest topic?

2.In a real classroom, it's better to make the class interactive and ask students to come on the board to solve hands on problems. But as part of the interview, there's little time to do this. I can surely ask quick questions to the audience. How to balance between interactivity and time limit?

Comment: Is that really a chalk talk in your field, because in the fields I am aware of chalk talks are about future funding plans without slides. This sounds more like a teaching demo.

Comment: yes, a teaching chalk demo, not funding related

Answer (score 5):

1. If you already know which topic is the most desirable one to the selection committee (perhaps, it's a subject they are not offering right now or willing to commit to a full-time instructor instead of a part-time one), I suggest choosing that topic. Also, if you know that your teaching material and/or approach for a specific topic is relatively unique and could be of interest to students (e.g., applied discussion of theories or real-world case studies), you might go that way. Other than those, I suggest sticking to the topic with which you're most comfortable.
2. I think Observing time limits during interviews is important and neglecting them could make you nervous. So engaging with the audience is OK as long as you don't waste time or enter into a heated discussion.

Good luck with your interview.

Answer (score 2):

> Candidate is to teach 1 out of several topics given. Should there not be any preferential topic to be taught in the eye of the interviewers? Is there any disadvantage not to choose the hardest topic?

I find it unlikely that they are suggesting "worse topics" to see whether you know to avoid them -- that does not sound like a good faith effort to learn about the candidates' teaching skills.  I think you should assume good faith, which in this situation means that they are equally open to a talk on all the topics they gave you.  Having made that assumption, I think you should rule out topics on which you have less than complete mastery (if any), and among the remaining topics you should think a bit about what kind of talk you would or could give.  Then you should pursue the topic on which you feel you can give the best talk.

In my experience (in a mathematics department at a large research university), when your teaching is being observed / evaluated, it is usually for courses that serve the broadest teaching needs of the department.  E.g in a mathematics department this would often be calculus.  It tends to be taken as a given that if you have a PhD in subfield X, that you will do well (or well enough) in teaching an advanced course on topic X.  The reason for this is that in more advanced courses the students are (generally!) more interested, more independent and more mature, and so they need (or so we tend to think) more of a subject area expert than someone with mastery of particular teaching techniques. So I see no particular advantage in selecting the most advanced topic unless you really think that (i) this is a subject the department needs a new hire to teach, (ii) you know the subject extremely well and (iii) other candidates may not.

> In a real classroom, it's better to make the class interactive and ask students to come on the board to solve hands on problems. But as part of the interview, there's little time to do this. I can surely ask quick questions to the audience. How to balance between interactivity and time limit?

I think it's definitely awkward to try to interact with the people who are hiring you as though they were students in your course.  On the other hand, "How to balance between interactivity and time limit?" is a question that is just as important when you are actually teaching a course!  If you are being given a full class period, I would plan out a full lecture, including time to do whatever interactive activities you think best.  You might say "At this point I would ask the students to spend a couple minutes trying to solve X" and then see to what extent the faculty interviewing you want to play along.  If you are being given less time, you have to plan accordingly, and you may want to ask what the expectations are given that you have less than a full lecture to give.

Comment: excellent thx. u convince me that im better off teaching topics in calculus. the teaching chalk talk~half an hr. there'll b real students sitting there. given that time limit and setting, is there any specific advice from u?